# Do I need the url of the hosts phpmyadmin to affect their database

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am tasked with making changes to someones site. They have provided FTP details that they got from their host, but not access to the MySQL database.

I have the database connection details, i.e. the username, database name, password and "localhost" for the IP, which would be the IP of the site.

However I do not have a link to their phpmyadmin. When my client asked them for the details they simply said back "the details are in the code for the DB connection".

however I wasnt looking for those details, I was looking for the actual link to their phpmyadmin.

Is this a normal request from myself? Or am I expected to access their database via another means?

Thank you

Comment: PhPMyAdmin is just a PhP interface to the database, of course you can make changes to a database without that. That said, there might be other restrictions set that may block you from acessing it, but you don't need it. That said, You could aswell use any installed version of PHPMyAdmin, use the connections settings you got, and that's it...

Comment: if u have host-name, username and password then you should be able to connect with their database.

Comment: @Prashant not necessarily, databases are often restricted to connections from `localhost` for security reasons, unless he has access to SSH port forwarding remote connections are not possible.

Comment: @Bartdude, you wrote "You could aswell use any installed version of PHPMyAdmin, use the connections settings you got, and that's it" Sorry for the stupid question, but how do I enter the IP, i.e when going to log in the only thing I enter is username and password

Comment: @Adrian you connect to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. The point is that YOU don't do it, but your script that will be executed locally on the server.

Comment: ah, I see, sorry, so basically write out my commands in PHP (or whatever language Im using) and then do them simply run that script instead of doing it via phpmyadmin? That makes sense I guess

Comment: Yes, you manage the connection in your script, upload the script via FTP to the server and then execute it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: You do not need access to phpmyadmin to affect their database.

What you DO need is access to the server to deploy scripts which will then execute SQL commands locally, which is what you got via FTP.

From what you described you have to get the DB login credentials from the existing script that manages the DB connection, and use that for your own scripts or modify the existing ones.

Nothing from what you stated would indicate they even have phpmyadmin installed. And from a security point of view, it is a wise choice.